# How to replace dynamic keyword in WindowsPhone

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, delegates, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to use some of my code from a Silverlight application in a WindowsPhone application. However I have a problem replacing the dynamic keyword with something else, so that my code still compiles and works.
I have a list of dynamic objects

```
private readonly List<dynamic> _awaitingActionsList = new List<dynamic>();
```

this list is used to store delegates of this signature

```
Action<T> where T: class
```

In other part of my class I invoke the delegates using this code

```
foreach (var action in _awaitingActionsList)
{
    InvokeAction(action)
}
```

InvokeAction function looks like this

```
public void InvokeAction<T>(Action<T> action)
{
    action.Invoke(someObject);
}
```

Thanks to dynamic keyword this code was working well on Silverlight, however dynamic keyword is not present in WindowsPhone, so I was wondering how to replace it. I don't want to change the signature of function InvokeAction, because thanks to use generics and Action I can pass delegates to function like this:

```
InvokeAction<SomeType>(val => val.DoStuff(param));
```

Comment: What if `someObject` isn't `T`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `List<Delegate>` and call the `DynamicInvoke` method.

It will be slow, but `dynamic` is also slow.
(I don't know which is slower)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have no idea how to modify my function (InvokeAction) so that I could still use lambda expression syntax.

Comment: @John: Add a second overload.